# aspnet core publish copies file even if it set to Do Not Copy

Tags: asp.net-core

I set sqlite db file to not to be published by changing Copy to output directory to Do not copy. But it copies it still after publish and also the project changed to:

`<None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" />`

is it a bug (I am running 5.0.2) or I misunderstand how publish works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="app.db" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```